# Is Java MAM Coming?

Tags: tangle, masked-authenticated-messaging, java

I'm developing a Java REST web services app that works with the Tangle. Currency won't be involved, just data messages, as from sensors.

I think MAM is the technology for me, but I am not seeing any MAM Java API. I've downloaded and used the *mam.client.js*, and played around a bit by cloning *publishPrivate.js* and trying to invoke it from Java using the 
Nashorn Script Engine*—but I am currently running into *ScriptExceptions* having to do with the JS arrow function =>. I may post a question about this later, but for now I'd like to know if a MAM Java API is coming? If so, when is it expected?

Comment: Hi Bob, questions about guessing future releases are not a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. To emphasize that I closed the question. Anyways mihi's information answered your question already.

Comment: We are working on a java mam lib

Answer (score 2):

> Since iota.lib.java is a community effort (not written by the foundation), I assume a MAM library would have to be written by the community as well. – mihi♦